# Stimulsoft Reports.NET Custom function is not working properly

Tags: .net, stimulsoft

Like the title, I'm facing a difficulty of adding a custom sort function to a dataset.
Here is the [link](https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?p=168494#p168494) to my question in the forum, it already includes all the details.

My current project is fetching the report data from a different source, so I would try to avoid modify the data class as much as possible.